# Run scripts on start or end of xsession

Tags: linux-mint

I am trying to find a way to run a script on sleep before an x session ends, because the script requires an active x session to execute properly. Storing the script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` did not work (and returned errors related to a non-existent x session). Any ideas where to put the script?

Update in response to comments

```
king@death-star /etc/acpi $ cat 01_revert_kb_on_sleep 
#!/bin/bash
touch ~/Desktop/touchfile_my_script_acpi
case "$1" in
hibernate|suspend)
sh -c "/home/king/Desktop/Scripts/rotate_desktop normal; /home/king/Desktop/Scripts/misc/my_keyboard on" 2> ~/Desktop/revert_kb_error_log.txt ;;
#thaw|resume)

king@death-star /etc/acpi $ ls
total 1MB
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 1MB Jun 11 23:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 163 root root 1MB Jun 11 23:41 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1MB Jun 11 23:36 01_revert_kb_on_sleep

king@death-star /etc/acpi $ ps -ef| grep acpid
root      1070     1  0 23:41 ?        00:00:00 acpid -c /etc/acpi/events -s /var/run/acpid.socket
king      3499  2574  0 23:52 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --colour=auto acpid
```

Comment: I am pretty sure ACPI is what you want. Make sure `acpid` is running and then you can put your scripts in `/etc/acpi/...` directory.

Comment: I tried putting the script in `/etc/acpi/` then triggering an xsession restart by restarting the computer. There was no output at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I may have misread your question. You say "run a script on sleep before an x session ends." So you want it to run on sleep? Or before X session ends?

Comment: When I put the laptop to sleep, the X session ends before my script runs. I am trying to have my script run after I send the sleep command, but before the x session closes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1.

a. Enable and start the `acpi` service.

b. Run the `acpi_listen` command and try putting the computer to sleep via various methods (pushing the power button, closing the lid, etc.)

c. Find out what events are triggered, when you do the above. In my case they were: `button/lid LID close` and `button/sleep SBTN 00000080 00000000`

Step 2.

a. Create the file `/etc/acpi/events/my_events` with the following:

```
event=(button/sleep SBTN|button/lid LID close)
action=/etc/acpi/my_script.sh
```

Substitute the events in the `event=` line with your events.

b. Create the file `/etc/acpi/my_script.sh` with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
/home/king/Desktop/Scripts/rotate_desktop normal
/home/king/Desktop/Scripts/misc/my_keyboard on
```

NB. You might need to add `export DISPLAY=:0` before the scripts to get access to your X session.

NB2: Your scripts will run with `root` user credentials. To run with your user credentials, you might want to do:

```
sudo -u king /home/king/Desktop/Scripts/rotate_desktop normal
sudo -u king /home/king/Desktop/Scripts/misc/my_keyboard on
```

c. Make the file `/etc/acpi/my_script.sh` executable:

```
chmod +x /etc/acpi/my_script.sh
```

d. Restart the `acpi` service.

Step 3. Share and enjoy.